# Pass dynamically generated parameters to command inside script

Tags: bash, parameters, parameter-passing

I have a script which calls the `rsync` command with some dynamically generated parameters but I'm having trouble passing them correctly.

Here's some excerpt:

```
logfile="$logDir/$(timestamp) $name.log"
echo "something" >> "$logfile"

params="-aAXz --stats -h --delete --exclude-from $exclude --log-file=$logfile $src $dest"
if [ "$silent" = "" ]; then
    params="-v $params --info=progress2"
fi
rsync $params
```

If the logfile is e.g. `/tmp/150507 test.log`, the `something` statement is actually written to `/tmp/150507 test.log`, but `rsync` writes its logs to `/tmp/150507` (everything after the first blank removed).

If I explicitly quote the name of the logfile in the params, rsync throws an exception:

```
params="-aAXz --stats -h --delete --exclude-from $exclude --log-file=\"$logfile\" $src $dest"
```

The error:

> rsync: failed to open log-file "/tmp/150507: No such file or directory (2)
>   Ignoring "log file" setting.

How can I generate the params dynamically without losing the ability to use blanks in the filenames?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More quoting needed around log file name:

```
declare -a params

params=(-aAXz --stats -h --delete --exclude-from "$exclude" --log-file="$logfile" "$src" "$dest")

if [[ "$silent" = "" ]]; then
    params=( -v "${params[@]}" --info=progress2 )
fi

rsync "${params[@]}"
```

This is the case where you should consider using BASH arrays to constitute a dynamic command line.

Comment: Ain't that exactly what I mentioned in the 2nd half of my post (starting with "If I explicitly quote...") which leads to the `rsync` error?

Comment: @suamikim, no, because in that 2nd half of your post you're creating a _string_; in the answer here you're creating an _array_.

Comment: @anubhava, ...though the `-v "$params"` is a bit odd; you're adding the first element of the array in directly after the `-v`? I think a more accurate representation would be `params=( -v "${params[@]}" --info=progress2 )`; it's not `+=` because the OP is replacing the prior first argument with `-v`.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy for your insight. It is corrected now